2024 Community Moderator Election Results
Moderator election #6 on Cryptography has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

They will be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here or view a summary report online.

I'd like to thank both participants for stepping up and making sure that there was an interesting round of voting this time around, and bdegnan specifically for getting it going! And of course thanks to all the 151 voters, great that so many decided to voice their opinion. If you would like a moderator, then don't forget to visit the review queue's, perform tag edits, participate on meta and all that good stuff. It's amazing how much you all can do on this site without having the ♦.
